# GAE SDK and Launcher fails to run

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've just installed GAE SDK on a new computer and it failed to start.
When I open GAE Launcher it warns about errors, and log file has this.

> WARNING:root:   Warning: Prerequisites for App Engine development are
>   missing!
>
> A valid python binary must be available.  In addition,   the App
>   Engine SDK must be installed.  Here are the current   values we found:
>
> ```
> python = None
> App Engine SDK root = C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
> ```
>
> Please install the missing pieces and restart the launcher.   If
>   these are installed but the Launcher failed to find them,   you can
>   configure their location by editing Launcher preferences.
>
> The Launcher preferences can be modified by selecting Edit >
>   Preferences.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):

A long list of traces there.

I've re-installed both Python and GAE SDK. Checked the PATH variables.
It's: `C:\python27\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\`

But it doesn't work!
How could I fix this?
I would appreciate any help on this.

**Upd**. I tried removing  C:/users/username/Google/google_appengine_projects.ini this file.
The project is addede to the Launcher but it freezes the time I'm starting it. (server doesn't start)

Logs are:

> 2013-11-29 10:05:14 Running command:
>   "['C:\Python27\python.exe', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py',
>   '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000',
>   u'C:\Users\\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\\u0414\u0438\u0441\u043a
>   Google\Work\E\Adriatika\\app-engine\adriatika]"

```
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>   File
> "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__   File "wx\_core.pyc", line
> 7487, in _BootstrapApp   File "launcher\app.pyc", line 53, in OnInit  
> File "launcher\app.pyc", line 97, in _CreateModels   File
> "launcher\maintable.pyc", line 35, in __init__   File
> "launcher\maintable.pyc", line 96, in _LoadProjects   File
> "launcher\project.pyc", line 63, in ProjectWithConfigParser   File
> "launcher\project.pyc", line 285, in _LoadFromConfigParser   File
> "ConfigParser.pyc", line 520, in get ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No
> option 'name' in section: '0'
```

Comment: Anyone? Please? I'm getting nervous. My work is stuck.

Comment: It may be a issue of using wrong version of python. Is it properly installed?

Comment: I tried Python27 64-bit version. Then a regular 32-bit.
I'll try to re-install it probably

Comment: Ok, I re-installed Python, and installed previous SDK version (1.8.7) -- still the same. Just don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a temporary fix.
First of all I removed everything and installed Python from scratch.
I also installed a previous version of GAE SDK (1.8.7)

Then I moved my working folder. Cause it had cyrillic utf symbols in its title. And I guess GAE Parser didnt like those symbols.
After all that I could finally launch GAELauncher.